# AddToRoleAsync fails to find Role

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have a small test app using Asp.net Core Identity.
In the startup I check that certain system roles are in place:

```
if(await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(“SYSADMIN”) == null)
{
  _context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole(“SYSADMIN”));
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Then I check and create a system admin account if it doesn’t exist:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, config["AdminPassword"]);
```

I then try and add that user to the SYSADMIN role:

```
if (result == IdentityResult.Success)
{                  
  await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, “SYSADMIN”);
}
```

but get an error that the role does not exist. I can, however, see the role with the above name in `AspNetRoles` and when I run the app for a second time, it doesn’t go into the `_context.Roles.Add()` section as `_roleManager.FindByNameAsync` returns the role.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or know whats going on as to why its failing?

**edit**
I notice NormalisedName is null though in the DB - is that what it is using to match?

Comment: looks to me like you are being inconsistent and trying to pre-normalize the role name. if IDPPlatform.System.Roles.OrgAdmin is a string constant that would normalize to SYSADMIN you should just use the constant everywhere. methods like _roleManager.FindByNameAsync will normalize it inside the method so you don't need to pre-normalize it. same with _userManager.AddToRoleAsync

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. It does resolve to "SYSADMIN" and the constant is indeed used everywhere, I just replaced it in this example to show what it resolved as that is the string that gets put in the name column in SQL Server. I notice NormalisedName is null though in the DB - is that what it is using to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this looks like a bug to me. If you use the constructor that takes only a string, it populates the name, but not the normalised name. It would appear that the normalised name is matched on in `AddToRoleAsync` so it'll never work.

I needed to use the following to force the NormalizedName to be populated:

```
_context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole("SYSADMIN")
{
  NormalizedName = "SYSADMIN"
});
```

And its now working.
I'll file a bug with the team and hopefully it'll get fixed.

Comment: I was having the same issue. Thanks for the workaround. Probably this is exactly how it's supposed to work.